# How to add slds-line-clamp to a lightning-datatable?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system, lightning-datatable

SLDS's [slds-line-clamp](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/line-clamp/) is a good way to truncate multi-line text at a fixed number of lines.

But it appears awkward to apply this to text cells in a [lightning-datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example). This column data approach applies the class to the table cell (and so messes the whole table up) not to the container of the text:

```
cellAttributes: { class: 'slds-line-clamp' },
```

and this column data approach does not output the class at all:

```
typeAttributes: { class: 'slds-line-clamp' },
```

I also don't see any styling hooks related to line clamping. So is [creating a custom datatype](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_table_custom_types) the only way to go here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI doable via a custom datatype:

```
import LightningDatatable from 'lightning/datatable';
import textInDivWithClass from './textInDivWithClass.html';

/**
 * Allows e.g. slds-line-clamp to be applied to a text cell.
 */
export default class CustmDatatable extends LightningDatatable {
    static customTypes = {
        textInDivWithClass: {
            template: textInDivWithClass,
            standardCellLayout: true,
            typeAttributes: ['text', 'class'],
        },
    };
}
```

with the template HTML:

```
<template>
    <div class={typeAttributes.class}>{typeAttributes.text}</div>
</template>
```

and configured by column data of:

```
    {
        label: 'Description',
        fieldName: 'Description__c',
        type: 'textInDivWithClass',
        typeAttributes: {
            class: 'slds-line-clamp',
            text: {fieldName: 'Description__c'},
        },
        wrapText: true,
        hideDefaultActions: true,
        sortable: true,
    },
```

But in the end I've gone back to the simple one line truncation of `wrapText: false` with some column width adjustment to make the table look OK. Truncating at say 3 lines is still truncation, so overall seems better to go for the compactness of a single line per table row.